# How to convert string into an array?

Tags: javascript, arrays, string

I'm working with this page: [ITEM INFO](http://www.roblox.com/catalog/json?browse.aspx?Subcategory=2&CurrencyType=0&pxMin=0&pxMax=0&SortType=0&SortAggregation=3&SortCurrency=0&PageNumber=1&LegendExpanded=true&Category=2)

and I turn the page into a string:

```
var info = document.getElementsByTagName("pre")[0].innerHTML;
```

The entire page is already in the format of an array, so is there a conversion function that will convert it from the string into an array?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Use `JSON.parse(info)` to parse JSON text into Javascript Array.

```
var info = document.getElementsByTagName("pre")[0].innerHTML;
var results = JSON.parse(info);
```

Now in `results` variable will be an array of parsed JavaScript objects.

Comment: Can you edit that to show how I would apply that? Im a bit of a noob to this.